# How to transfer to ip address other than virtual ip to start Apache IoTDB?

Tags: ip-address, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Every time I started Apache IoTDB, the virtual ip (127.0.0.1) is displayed. If I want to enter IoTDB through other ip accounts, how can I do this? I tried the official guide tutorial, use the startup command: `shell > sbin\start-cli.bat -h 10.129.187.21 -p 6667 -u root -pw root -disableIs08681 -maxPRC 18`, but the system immediately crashed. Are there any ways to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dn_rpc_address` in `iotdb-datanode.properties`directory of Apache IoTDB can be changed to `0.0.0.0`. If you are using a stand-alone version, changing this parameter will do the job and get access to other IP accounts.